# What is the key used in Session based windowing on Google dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I am new to dataflow. I came across this example in the google documentation.

```
PCollection<String> items = ...;
  PCollection<String> session_windowed_items = items.apply(
    Window.<String>into(Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardMinutes(10))));
```

1) In the above example, what would be the key used by dataflow to create windows?

2) If my input source is pubsub, should I set any message attributes and how can we specify what key dataflow should use when we go with Session based windowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements are assigned to sessions at the first grouping operation after the `Window.into`. Whatever key affects the `GroupByKey`, `Combine.perKey`, `Sum.perKey`, `CoGroupByKey`, etc. operation will be the grouping key.

You do not need to set message attributes to specify the key. Instead, you would write a `ParDo` to transform the existing elements into `KV<K, V>` values, and the key there would be derived from that.

You may want to read [about group-by-key for](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/group-by-key#groupbykey-with-windowing) for more info.